# Insert data into Couchdb using Angular 2

Tags: angular, couchdb

I'm new to Angular 2. How to save data from Api into Couchdb using Angular 2 and retrieve it back. Can anyone give example coding.

Comment: To communicate with couchdb you need to write some service in angular2. Can you brief what is your need? @rafaelcb21